# IIFE alternatives in Raku

Tags: raku

In Ruby I can group together some lines of code like so with a begin block:

```
x = begin
  puts "Hi!"
  a = 2
  b = 3
  a + b
end

puts x # 5
```

it's immediately evaluated and its value is the last value of the block (`a + b` here) (Javascripters do a similar thing with [IIFEs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE))

What are the ways to do this in Raku? Is there anything smoother than:

```
my $x = ({
  say "Hi!";
  my $a = 2;
  my $b = 3;
  $a + $b;
})();

say $x; # 5
```

Answer (score 12):

Insert a `do` in front of the block. This tells Raku to:

- Immediately *do* whatever follows the `do` on its right hand side;
- Return the value to the `do`'s left hand side:

```
my $x = do {
  put "Hi!";
  my $a = 2;
  my $b = 3;
  $a + $b;
}
```

---

That said, one rarely needs to use `do`.

Instead, there are many other IIFE forms in Raku that just work naturally without fuss. I'll mention just two because they're used extensively in Raku code:

```
with whatever { .foo } else { .bar }
```

You might think I'm being silly, but those are two IIFEs. They form lexical scopes, have parameter lists, bind from arguments, the works. Loads of Raku constructs work like that.

In the above case where I haven't written an explicit parameter list, this isn't obvious. The fact that `.foo` is called on `whatever` if `whatever` is defined, and `.bar` is called on it if it isn't, is both implicit and due to the particular IIFE calling behavior of `with`.

See also `if`, `while`, `given`, and many, many more.

---

What's going on becomes more obvious if you introduce an explicit parameter list with `->`:

```
for whatever -> $a, $b { say $a + $b }
```

That iterates `whatever`, binding two consecutive elements from it to `$a` and `$b`, until `whatever` is empty. If it has an odd number of elements, one might write:

```
for whatever -> $a, $b? { say $a + $b }
```

And so on.

---

Bottom line: a huge number of occurrences of `{...}` in Raku are IIFEs, even if they don't look like it. But if they're immediately after an `=`, Raku defaults to assuming you want to assign the lambda rather than immediately executing it, so you need to insert a `do` in that particular case.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Raku!

```
my $x = BEGIN {
    say "Hi!";
    my $a = 2;
    my $b = 3;
    $a + $b;
}
```

I guess the common ancestry of Raku and Ruby shows :-)

Also note that to create a constant, you can also use `constant`:

```
my constant $x = do {
    say "Hi!";
    my $a = 2;
    my $b = 3;
    $a + $b;
}
```

If you can have a single statement, you can leave off the braces:

```
my $x = BEGIN 2 + 3;
```

or:

```
my constant $x = 2 + 3;
```

Regarding blocks: if they are in sink context (similar to "void" context in some languages), then they will execute just like that:

```
{
    say "Executing block";
}
```

No need to explicitely call it: it will be called for you :-)

Comment: `BEGIN` in Raku is very different from `begin` in Ruby. If the former appears in a loop or function or other reusable construct, it'll only be evaluated once, not each loop iteration.

Comment: Aha, so it is more like the ENTER phaser then?  And not a compile time construct?

Comment: It's a broader-scoped ENTER phaser. ENTER will run once per block entry (so if you put it inside of a function, every time the function is called). BEGIN will run once per *file*, so as soon as the file is loaded, BEGIN blocks run once and never run again.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Aren't `begin` / `end` in Ruby pretty much just block delimiters, following Pascal family PLs, and thus equivalents of `{` / `}` in Raku to write code blocks, at least loosely speaking?

Comment: @raiph Loosely speaking, that's accurate. Hence why I upvoted your answer ;)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yay, bullseye. :) Gotta love the way that reducing precision increases accuracy. (Or something like that...)